# Tcl/Tk creating buttons/widgets in a newly created window

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I want to create a new window when a particular button is pressed and the newly created window should contain labels/entries/buttons. My code goes something like this..

```
. configure  -width  400 -height 400 
label .header -text "Bitfields"
place .header -x 5 -y 0
 .................................
toplevel .window -width 100 -height 120
```

Now I want to create a button/label on the newly created window . How am I supposed to do that? Google mostly provides examples for tkinter which I think is linked to python which I am not using. As a sub question how can I make this window appear when a button is clicked from the parent window?

Comment: For your first question, just create the widgets and name them after the name of the new window. E.g. a button in the window can be called `.window.button` and it'll be placed in the window.

Comment: Use `pack` or `grid` instead of `place` unless you _really_ know what you're doing; `place` is significantly trickier to use well.

Comment: although `place` is easy to understand (just place a button at a certain position), `pack` and `grid` makes it much easier to develop applications (you don't have to measure the place where the button should be yourself) and provides support for resized windows. (Try that with place)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a button/label on the newly created window (called `.window`):

```
button .window.button1 -text "ok"
```

To make a window appear when a button is clicked from the parent window:

```
proc showWindow {w} {
    catch {destroy $w}
    toplevel $w
    button $w.button1 -text "ClickMe"
    pack $w.button1
}
. configure  -width  400 -height 400 
button .header -text "Bitfields" -command "showWindow .window"
place .header -x 5 -y 0
```